# Lock checking of existing file section

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, locking

In my website I use a controller to generate thumbnail of images. my code looks like:

```
var filePath = getThumbnailPath(); 
if (!File.Exists(filePath) 
{
    ... create thumbnail  
}    
return new Filestream(...)
```

The problem is that if two users request the same thumbnail and if this is not created I will get exception when creating it. 
How can I efficiently use a lock on the file name object without introducing too much overhead?

Refactored code after Aristos's comment:

```
 Mutex m = new Mutex(false, originalImagePath);
 m.WaitOne();
 try
 {
     if (!File.Exists(originalImagePath))
     { 
          ... create thumbnail
     }
 }
 finally
 {
     m.ReleaseMutex();
 }
```

Comment: I'd use a queue, and probably a small cache so you'll get it once, and the second request will get it from the cache.

Comment: I use mutex to lock the thumbnail creation, I also place the image file name as the name of the mutex, and I do not have any bottleneck. Of cource ones I have made the thumbnail I keep it (cache) and serve it on next requests.

Comment: shame on me ... mutex is exactly what I need. Can you post some code ... for the accepted answer ... and I am sure that you will save the day for others like me.

Comment: Mutex is a system wide blocking object, if you have a single web server - i.e. one process, you don't need to use it. Instead consider using `lock`, it is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Delegate creation of the thumbnails to other service. User will *produce* a request to create a thumbnail. Another service will *consume* this request and do the actual work.

What is a service, you can choose for your own. It can be a WCF service, a Windows service, a message queue or something else.

It is not usually a good idea to use locking in ASP.NET website directly as it will introduce a bottleneck.

Comment: if I delegate it to another service and I have two requests for the same resource ... one of the requests will have to wait till the resource is created ... this will anyway block the asp.net thread till the resource is available. Am I wrong? I want to use something like a ConcurrentDictionaryto add lock on a specific object that is associated to hte resource key. But the output code looks very very bad :(

Comment: I think I missed the big picture of your solution. You say that I should return a redirect to another service that takes care of the resources? Since it is an asp net request I need to return something to the user.

Comment: Now I understood. My first impression was that I will delay the check to another service.

Comment: Would the question just become "how do it lock in a my service?"

Comment: "It is not usually a good idea to use locking in ASP.NET website directly as it will introduce a bottleneck" All-encompassing and not true. Depends entirely on the way locks are used.

Comment: No need, the questions has already been answered, second comment to the original post. As for using locks, I guess you can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: well, in my defense, I didnt really try.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET sites have a concept of being able to run more than one process (e.g. web farms, etc.).  `lock` only locks within a single process.  If, for whatever reason, your code ran in more than one process, you'd be back to the same problem.

Also, your use of the dictionary needs to be made thread-safe.  The way it is, it could write more than one value for the same filename.

I'd recommend using a named `Mutex`.  This allows mutual exclusion across processes.  The name of the mutex can simply be the filename.  No need for a dictionary.

Making a network request to another service seems like it it was introduce even more latency into requests to your site.  (e.g. a request to your site for an image needs to make a secondary network request to this "Service" to get the image --or get the location of the image).